# In Android do I need to support both compat Action Bar and regular one?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I have an old Android app that was target at API level 8 (2.2). I'm planning to update it to targetSDK 4.4.2. Main change will be using the Action Bar on pretty much every `Activity`. Right now it uses the old menu.

I know I have to use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` to support Action Bar for older phones.

Is it recommended to implement the "regular" android.app.ActionBar for APIs 11 and greater alongside `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`?

Will they look any different?

Comment: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ActionBar` wont look different at all for APIs 11 or greater.

You can keep using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can use android.support.v7.app.ActionBar for all API levels.